# How to fix these errors for my program because its saying can't open file 'd:\\pythion proj\\import requests.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, speech-recognition

This is the porblem that I am expriecing and I am very confused on how I can fix it.

```
Exception has occurred: ConnectionError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd:\\pythion projLOVE'
  File "D:\pythion proj\import requests.py", line 14, in read_file
    with open(LOVE, 'rb') as _file:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "D:\pythion proj\import requests.py", line 21, in <module>
    upload_response = requests.post(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, data=read_file(BASE_DIR + 'LOVE'))
```

I expected it to give the final outpuit because I am trying to do a speech recognition program capable of transcribing human voice into text by using an existing audio file as source.

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious, file does not exist. The `LOVE` path, `d:\\pythion projLOV` doesn't exist in your computer.

Comment: The thing is I have the file, it is on the D driver and can be located on the pythion proj folder